# Why is my post jQuery Ajax request seinding JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I downloaded some code and in it was the following fragment:

```
 function GetCommentBySessionIDWCF_JSON() {
            varType = "POST";
            varUrl = "service/CommentSessionIDWCFService.svc/GetCommentsByPost";
            varData = '{"SessionID": "' + '123' + '"}';
            varContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            varDataType = "json";
            varProcessData = true;

            //now to do the clever stuff
            $.ajax({
                type: varType, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
                url: varUrl, // Location of the service
                data: varData, //Data sent to server
                contentType: varContentType, // content type sent to server
                dataType: varDataType, //Expected data format from server
                processdata: varProcessData, //True or False
                success: function (data) {//On Successfull service call

                    $.each(data.GetCommentsByPostResult, function (e) {
                        alert(e.CommentText);
                    });

                },
                error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
            });
```

What im wondering is why I have to send JSON with this post? I read the jQuery documentation and it says:

*"Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below)."*

But when I changed the JSON in 'data' to a string I get a 400 error. why?

Comment: Should just be able to default the data type to string if you remove it from that script.

Comment: set a dataType on your ajax options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not JSON, it's an object containing key/value pairs that is rendered to HTTP `?param=value` to be sent to the server.

Comment: Only for GET request. he's sending POST.

Comment: Principle is the same, the query string is just not visible on the URL.

Comment: ah I see, so what im wondering is this standard practice in a post scenario? Do all posts consist of key value pairs?

Comment: That's just how you send data in HTTP requests. GET POST PUT DELETE, you name it. They all use the same mechanism.

Comment: cool yeah okay still learning just looked at the definition of POST in wikipedia and yeah it makes sense. Over and above Get it just has key value pairs that are urlencoded...